# in Intellij, clicking on resources folder opens the project structure

Tags: intellij-idea

Made a new Java project, using Spring & Maven.

When I double-click on `resources` folder (which is empty) the `Project Structure` window is popping, why is that? Does it means that I am missing something in the `Project Structure`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any empty marked folder causes this behavior, and it is intended. Once you add a file inside, the behavior changes to fold/unfold the directory.